# Method with a return type that implements multiple interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

Currently I have the following:

```
interface IMyInterfaceReturnType : IEnumerable<string>, IDisposable
{
}

interface IMyInterface
{
    IMyInterfaceReturnType MyInterfaceMethod();
}
```

Is there a way that I can alter the method signature of MyInterfaceMethod() such that I can express that I will return an object that is both IEnumerable and Disposable without creating an intermediate interface?  Say:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    IEnumerable<string>, IDisposable MyInterfaceMethod();
}
```

Comment: What kind of problem would this solve? I ask because I try to see the need for this kind of thing. Yes, you can do this using generics, as have already been answered, but what exactly did this solve?

Comment: To be specific, no, there is no way to say "This will return any odd type that will implement these N interfaces". You can only say "This will return this specific type, that happens to also implement these N interfaces". I'm not sure the generics solution is what you're after though.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I want to return a class which iterates through an open file (while encapsulating that logic).  Providing the IEnumerable allows the user to iterate through lines while the IDisposible part allows the caller to close the underlying file stream once they are done.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I find that odd that there is no way to return "any odd type that will implement these N interfaces" as one can create a class/interface which implements any N interfaces ([even when there are name collisions between the interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4taxa8t2.aspx))

Comment: A method will only ever have 1 return type and .NET does not have the concept of "any type that implements N interfaces", so this is not possible. Even with the generics syntax, from the answer below, you still have to settle on one type for `T`. The constraint is that the only legal types you can specify for `T` are ones that also happen to implement those interfaces but the return type of the method will still be that single `T`.

Comment: I think I've read this before, but I can't find the Q&A. The consensus was for this exact requirement to return the most derived type, and document that the return value must be disposed by the caller. Found something like it: [Determining if IDisposable should extend an interface or be implemented on a class implementing said interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368663/determining-if-idisposable-should-extend-an-interface-or-be-implemented-on-a-cla).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with generics:

```
interface IMyInterface<T> where T :IEnumerable<string>, IDisposable 
{
    T MyInterfaceMethod();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this require the interface caller to specify the return type.  My code above doesn't require the caller to specify a return type.

Comment: I'm not sure this helps very much. Not sure what OP is really wanting here.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the first block is legal.

Comment: Yes it is, but unfortunately there is no syntax for declaring what you want without generics, or ... you can of course declare your own interface that implies those two others but I doubt that's what you want either.